# Java ZonedDateTime does not adjust UTC to local zone

Tags: java, java-time, zoneddatetime, localdatetime

This piece of code:

```
String dateString = "20210811T021500Z";
String dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'";

System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, dateFormat).toString());
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, dateFormat).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Budapest")).toString());
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, dateFormat), ZoneId.of("Europe/Budapest")).toString());
```

Outputs this:

```
2021-08-11T02:15
2021-08-11T02:15+02:00[Europe/Budapest]
2021-08-11T02:15+02:00[Europe/Budapest]
```

How can I print the adjusted time? I expect the result to be `2021-08-11T04:15`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Well, it is a LocalDateTime.

Comment: Oh, good point.  OK, so how does OP expect their program to magically interpret it as UTC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not parse your date to a `LocalDateTime`. A `LocalDateTime` has no information about timezones, but for your calculation here, you absolutely *need* to know that the input date is in UTC, in order to compute the time difference from `Europe/Budapest`.

Parse the date to a `ZonedDateTime` instead:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssX");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
// zdt = 2021-08-11T02:15Z
```

Notice how the `Z` in the date string is not parsed literally as `'Z'`, but rather `X` - the zone offset. If you parsed it literally then there would be no timezone information in your date string.

Then, you can your desired output by calling [`withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-):

```
System.out.println(
    zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Budapest"))
); // 2021-08-11T04:15+02:00[Europe/Budapest]
```

Alternatively, you can give the zone to the formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssX")
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Budapest"));
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
System.out.println(zdt);
2021-08-11T04:15+02:00[Europe/Budapest]
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! I guess I understand the difference between `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` now. However, my next fail would have been the `'Z'` literal, so two birds with one stone.